# Supporting Multiple resolution devices Android

Tags: android, resolution, screen-resolution, htc-android

I am stuck in a situation.
I created an application for Samsung Galaxy Tab 7". The same application when i run on the HTC  Flyer it shows very small fonts.

I tried following :
I thought may be the screen of HTC Flyer is xhdmi so i crated folders accordingly

```
res -> values-large-xhdmi -> styles.xml -> <item textsize>20</item>
res -> values-large-> styles.xml -> <item textsize>16</item>
```

this is not working.. :( 
any help will be highly appreciable in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this recent blog post on sizes: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

> A typical 7” tablet has a 1024x600 mdpi screen. This also counts as a
>   large screen.
>
> The original Samsung Galaxy Tab is an interesting case. Physically it
>   is a 1024x600 7” screen and thus classified as “large”. However the
>   device configures its screen as hdpi, which means after applying the
>   appropriate ⅔ scaling factor the actual space on the screen is 682dp x
>   400dp. This actually moves it out of the “large” bucket and into a
>   “normal” screen size. The Tab actually reports that it is “large”;
>   this was a mistake in the framework’s computation of the size for that
>   device that we made. Today no devices should ship like this.

So you need to think of the Galaxy as a large sized screen but with hdpi.
THe HTC Flyer will be large sized screen but with mdpi.

When specifying sizes you need to stick with dp, as this normalizes all sizes to scale appropriately for the different density screens. Use a dimension to specify in a xml value resource.

As milind hinted (i think), it is probably better to use the same style for these two screen sizes and specify a dimen resource. This resource can then be customized for the different displays.

The bottom line, however, is that you are using text size differences based on the screen size. The text size should be indicated in dp, so it will scale accordingly to any screen density. Really, the only resources that should be based on screen size are layouts.

Comment: Thanks lan, So as what i understand this is issue from Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" and in order to achieve similar output on all 7" tablet devices i should try to focus on HTC Flyer ? Please confirm.

Comment: Correct. Really, i think you only need different resources for screen sizes and orientations for layouts. For dimensions, stick with "dp" meseasurements, as it will scale accordingly for you. So in your particular problem, you should only need specify one text size.

Comment: Abhinava, i know you've probably gone over this before, but it may be worth it to read through this in depth:http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are plan to make Multiple resolution Supporting android application just you have care about image and xml  no other needs that you have same images with three different size putting in different  folders  like drawable-hdpi,  drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi. you can make style.xml common for all.

Thanks

Comment: thanks milind.. but i already mentioned .. i am worried only about the font sizes here... hence cannot help it via drawables.. and have to use styles.xml, even in this particular case.. its not working as expected.. Same image on HTC Flyer looks shrinked than it looks on Samsung Tablet 7" even both the devices are going to pool resource from drawable-hdpi.